# Sublime text 3 REPL MacOS

Tags: macos, python-3.x, sublimetext3, sublimerepl

When i choose in REPL, EVAL or TRANSFER i have the following error running a py:

```
Cannot find REPL for 'python'
```

I use python 3, and reading other post i make this changes to use in sublime text 3

1.Create a file name: Python3.sublime.build with the following code:

```
{
"path": "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/bin/",
"cmd": ["python3.3", "-u", "$file"],
"env":{},
"file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
"selector": "source.python"
}
```

Then i have the option to build a Python3 System

2.In settings in sublime REPL - Default i put this:

```
"default_extend_env": {"PATH": "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/bin/python3:{PATH}"},
```

and change the file `Main.sublime-menu` in located in `Packages/SublimeREPL/config/Python` with this:

```
[
     {
        "id": "tools",
        "children":
        [{
            "caption": "SublimeREPL",
            "mnemonic": "r",
            "id": "SublimeREPL",
            "children":
            [
                {"caption": "Python",
                "id": "Python",

                 "children":[
                    {"command": "repl_open",
                     "caption": "Python 3",
                     "id": "repl_python3",
                     "mnemonic": "p",
                     "args": {
                        "type": "subprocess",
                        "encoding": "utf8",
                        "cmd": ["/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/bin/python3", "-i", "-u"],
                        "cwd": "$file_path",
                        "syntax": "Packages/Python/Python.tmLanguage",
                        "external_id": "python",
                        "extend_env": {"PYTHONIOENCODING": "utf-8"}
                        }
                    },
                    {"command": "repl_open",
                     "caption": "Python 3 - IPython",
                     "id": "repl_python_ipython3",
                     "mnemonic": "p",
                     "args": {
                        "type": "subprocess",
                        "encoding": "utf8",
                        "autocomplete_server": true,
                        "cmd": {
                            "osx": ["/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/bin/python3", "-u", "${packages}/SublimeREPL/config/Python/ipy_repl.py"],
                            "linux": ["/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/bin/python3", "-u", "${packages}/SublimeREPL/config/Python/ipy_repl.py"],
                            "windows": ["/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/bin/python3", "-u", "${packages}/SublimeREPL/config/Python/ipy_repl.py"]
                        },
                        "cwd": "$file_path",
                        "syntax": "Packages/Python/Python.tmLanguage",
                        "external_id": "python",
                        "extend_env": {
                            "PYTHONIOENCODING": "utf-8",
                            "SUBLIMEREPL_EDITOR": "$editor"
                        }
                    }
                    }
                ]}
            ]
        }]
    }
]
```

I think there's must be an easy way to refer python 3 but i don't find it or not find clear, when i choose in Tools, SublimeREPL, Python and Python 3 it open a new tab with python 3

Answer (score 0):

Set Layout to "2 Rows" under View Menu.
Select "SublimeREPL:Python" from the Command Palette under Tools.

~Morgan (very new at this)

Answer (score -1):

"https://superuser.com/questions/755320/sublime-text-cant-find-interpreters-for-sublimerepl"
Was the deal/fix on my side. ** **REPL needs to be open first. . . .** **
Dunno if its the same for others, but this small detail was the key for me.
lol.
  Hope that helps